# Is there a way to count the number of files in the root directory of a web server using FTP or cPanel?

Tags: webserver, cpanel

I have a website on Bluehost and it's exceeding its file limit. I have a lot directories and I want to know which of them has the most files in it so that I could see weather I could delete them to lower the capacity of my total files. On Filezilla, I can see the number of files or directories but it's not counting the sub-directories.

Is there a way to count them without going through every folder and sub-folder? Another way is to download all of the files and count them on windows explorer but that will take a lot of time since, like I said, I have lots of files. In the cPanel of Bluehost, the file count option is no longer there with the new cPanel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In FileZilla, select the folder and go to *Server > Search remote files* (or press <kbd>F3</kbd>). Start search with no search criteria. All files in the folder, including its subfolders, will be listed in the *Results*. The status bar will show their count and total size.

---

It's somewhat easier with (my) WinSCP FTP client. There you can use [*File > Properties*](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_properties) (<kbd>F9</kbd>) and just click *Calculate* button.

In the latest WinSCP 6.0 beta, you can display the directory sizes even directly in [the *Size* column of file panel](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_file_panel#directory_sizes). Select the directories and go to *Files > Calculate Directory Sizes*.

In older versions, you can "abuse" the [synchronization function](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_synchronize). Start remote to local synchronization against an empty local folder. [Synchronization checklist window](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_synchronize_checklist) will show. On the window, all top-level subfolders will be listed (as they are "new" comparing to the empty local folder). Select all of them, right-click and select *Calculate*. WinSCP will calculate size of all the top-level subfolders individually. *(The next version of WinSCP will [have this functionality directly on the main window](https://winscp.net/tracker/41).)*